# Fallout 4 window is too small. How do I change the size of my screen?

Tags: fallout-4

My Fallout 4 wasn't loading so I switched it to windows mode but it's really small. Is there anyway I can make the window bigger?

Answer (score 7):

Before the game launches, where you select *Options* to change to *Window Mode*, you can adjust the resolution:

[image: Adjust Fallout options]

Otherwise, if you're trying to adjust the window to a more specific size, you can do so by editing *Fallout4Prefs.ini*. In Windows Explorer (I'm assuming Windows, if you use another OS I'm sure you can figure this out) navigate to your Fallout 4 saves folder, likely:

```
Documents\Fallout4
```

In here you'll find a file called *Fallout4Prefs.ini*. First make a backup in case you muck it up. Open this file in Notepad or your favourite text editor, and find the following values:

```
iSize H=450
iSize W=800
```

These refer to the *height* and *width* of your window, respectively. Change these values to whatever you would prefer. As an example:

```
iSize H=1280
iSize W=1900
```

Save the file, then relaunch Fallout 4. Once past the menu, you'll see the window is now at the size you set. Note these values only apply if you've selected *Window Mode* in Fallout 4

Answer (score -3):

you need to change your PC's resolution in display settings

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Comment: You never change your PC's display settings to change an application's resolution. It doesn't work that way anymore.